# Navigate | Class or File popup closes immediately in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having a annoying problem since I update IntelliJ IDEA Community to this version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2
Build #IC-172.3317.76, built on July 15, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b5 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.8.0-53-generic
```

There is a problem with "Main Menu/Navigate/Class" action. When a trigger this action using keyboard shortcut or menu access, most of time the "Enter class name" window is showed, but closes immediately.

Sometimes the action works ok, but most of time, not.

I'm using linux Mint 18.2 (Cinnamon).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a known issue, please follow it here for updates:

- [IDEA-173000](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173000) Navigate | File and Class popups disappear

Workaround (add the following via `Help` | **Edit Custom VM Options**):

- `-DactionSystem.xWindow.remove.focus.from.nonFocusable.popups=false`

[Downgrading](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html) to 2017.1 version is another option.

**UPDATE**: the issue is [resolved in 2017.2.3 release](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.2.3+Release+Notes).

Comment: After setting both VM options, I'm seeing that the modal does not get focus correctly. I end up needing to mouse to the modal. Opting for the downgrade.

Comment: @benkiefer try only the first VM option and don't change the `Hide navigation popups on focus loss` setting.

Comment: It's beyond my comprehension how 3 months was not sufficient to fix this bug in a product that claims to be the most advanced IDE on the market.

Comment: @AttilaMiklosi the bug was fixed several weeks ago and the fix has been tested since then. The fix will be released with the next update. Sorry for the delays, but there is a simple workaround, so the issue is not critical and we don't want to rush with the fix to no make it worse.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue in CLion 2018.2.4. 

If I use hotkeys to open the windows for entering a file name or an action name, as soon as I start typing a few characters it'll close the window and re-focus on my editor. 

Extremely frustrating and crippling to my productivity. Setting the VM option didn't seem to help my particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the release notes it's fixed in the latest release - 2017.2.3 (build number IU-172.3968.16) - 173000 is in the list: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.2.3+Release+Notes?fromIDE

Answer (score 1):

What ultimately worked for me was adding `-Dfocus.follows.mouse.workarounds=true` to my custom VM options (Help > Edit Custom VM Options).

I found this in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173000, mentioned above.

I use a tiling window manager (i3) which I suspect is related.

Comment: Works for me as well! (i3wm on ubuntu). The annoying behaviour started with 2018.1 and is gone now! thanks man